# TwoWay binding on WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm trying to build a simple Color Picker as a WPF UserControl, but I'm having trouble getting the selected color back to the main window.

My main window XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ColorPicker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ColorPicker"
        Title="TestWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding MyColor}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="100" Height="300"/>
        <view:WPFColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding MyColor, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" Height="300"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and the view model and code-behind:

```
namespace ColorPicker
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            MyColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        }

        public Brush MyColor { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TestViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

The WPFColorPicker usercontrol XAML is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ColorPicker.WPFColorPicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rtlfill" Fill="{Binding SelectedColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="60" Margin="10,10,10,10" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedColor}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,81" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="colorList">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding .}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="#FF211E1E" OpacityMask="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and code-behind:

```
namespace ColorPicker
{
    public partial class WPFColorPicker : UserControl
    {
        List<Brush> brushList;

        public WPFColorPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            brushList = new List<Brush>() {
                new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255,  0,  0)),
                new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(  0,255,  0)),
                new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(  0,  0,255))};

            this.colorList.ItemsSource = brushList;
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(WPFColorPicker),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        public Brush SelectedColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem I'm having is that binding on SelectedColor (using MyColor from TestViewModel) doesn't work.

From looking at other questions on StackOverflow and various tutorials, I think have the UserControl set up correct to bind SelectedColor as a TwoWay DependencyProperty, but its not working.

Can someone provide me some insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `FrameworkElement` can have only one `DataContext` so when you do

```
DataContext = this;
```

in `UserControl` constructor you overwrite `DataContext` normally inherited through visual tree and that affects default binding context for `WPFColorPicker` and all children, including

```
<view:WPFColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding MyColor, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
```

Remove that line from `WPFColorPicker` constructor and instead give `UserControl` some name

```
<UserControl x:Class="ColorPicker.WPFColorPicker" ... x:Name="myUserControl">
```

and change bindings inside `UserControl` to use that name

```
<Rectangle ... Fill="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=SelectedColor}"/>
<ListBox ... SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=SelectedColor}">
```

**EDIT**

As a side note you need to be aware that `Brush` is compared by reference so `ListBox.SelectedValue` will not preselect value unless it's one of instances from the `brushList`, which is not possible as you create the list every time. Basically two different instances of `SolidColorBrush`, even with the same `Color`, are different for equality check

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I was being my own worst enemy there.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that your Window's DataContext is set to your ViewModel.*

Your colour picker is a `UserControl`, therefore the following binding:

```
SelectedColor="{Binding MyColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Is trying to find `MyColor` in the DataContext of the UserControl, not the parent window.

You can either give the window a name and use ElementName binding:

```
SelectedColor="{Binding DataContext.MyColor, ElementName=windowName, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Or even better, use a relative source binding:

```
SelectedColor="{Binding DataContext.MyColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: while I believe your solution worked, it seemed more appropriate for "fix" the UserControl (as described in the selected answer) than fixing the window trying to use the user control. Thanks!